# Is it possible to pass a method to another method?

Tags: c#

I'd like to have a method where I can pass another method (without any parameters).
In that method, there would be a thread to call the passed method.

Not really sure how to implement this but the whole idea is something like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MethodStarter(Greet)
}

void MethodStarter(Method method)
{
    ThreadStart starter = method;

    _thread = new Thread(starter) { IsBackground = true };
    _thread.Start();
}

void Greet()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SendAMessage), "Hello World");            
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SendAMessage), "How are you today?");         
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

void SendAMessage(object arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arg as string);
}
```

Comment: Have a look into "delegates". And then "Action" may be of interest, too.

Comment: you could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You kind of answered the question in your question, actually. Look at this line:

```
ThreadStart starter = method;
```

You are assigning `method` to a variable of type `ThreadStart`, so naturally, `method` should be of type `ThreadStart` as well:

```
void MethodStarter(ThreadStart method)
{
    // you don't actually need this line, just pass "method" directly
    // ThreadStart starter = method;

    _thread = new Thread(method) { IsBackground = true };
    _thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: that's very helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: plus 1 for providing a "real" answer :)